# Ember 1.0rc6 - Error messages on transitionTo, though it still works

Tags: routes, ember.js

I've set up an authenticatedRoute to redirect to the Login route in my app. However, I'm getting a strange error message during the transition.

```
Error while loading route: undefined ember.js?body=1:361
Uncaught undefined
```

These errors are somewhere in the ember source code, so I'm not sure what about my code is setting it off. I've looked over it a few times and cant find where im going wrong

```
App.AuthenticatedRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  beforeModel: (transition) ->
    if !App.Auth.signedIn
      return Ember.RSVP.reject();

  error: (reason, transition) ->
    loginController = @controllerFor('login')
    loginController.set('afterLoginTransition', transition)
    @transitionTo('login')

App.LoginRoute = Ember.Route.extend()

App.PromptsRoute = App.AuthenticatedRoute.extend
  model: -> App.Prompt.find()

App.LoginController = Ember.Controller.extend

  email:    null
  password: null
  remember: true
  loginError: null
  afterLoginTransition: null

  login: () ->
    self = @
    App.Auth.signIn
      data:
        email:    @get 'email'
        password: @get 'password'
        remember: @get 'remember'
    .done (response) ->
      self.clearForm()
      self.loginSucceeded()
    .fail (response) ->
      self.set('loginError', "Your username or password was incorrect. Please try again")

  clearForm: ->
    @set('loginError', null)
    @set('email', null)
    @set('password', null)
    @set('remember', true)

  loginSucceeded: ->
    transition = @get('afterLoginTransition')
    if transition
      transition.retry()
    else
      alert("Boink")
```

Comment: do you have a `LoginRoute` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I see wrong is the error handler. It needs to be inside an `events` object on the `AuthenticatedRoute`.

```
events: {
  error: (reason, transition) ->
    loginController = @controllerFor('login')
    loginController.set('afterLoginTransition', transition)
    @transitionTo('login')
}
```

Besides that, clearly something is `undefined`. What/where exactly that should be seen in the stacktrace that follows the exception message in the dev tools console. The stacktrace would at some level show what method in your app code triggers the exception.

Try posting a jsbin if possible.